# How actually work ini_set in php?

Tags: php

I'm using **ini_set()** php function for decrease maximum execution time. I have no problem with it, but I would like to know what, how that function really work. I thought it may be overwrite **php.ini** file so I viewed maximum execution time in php.ini file. It hasn't any changes there, same value as before. Then how worked it? Is this php file changed maximum execution time value by itself only for executed moment?

Comment: I sets the value of a parameter in the interpreter. It does not change any file. The value is valid only for the script which set it and only until that script ends or changes the value again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ini_set()` is used to set a value for some configuration option.
 This can also be done by manually editing **php.ini** file.
What the `ini_set()` function does as opposed to editing the config file, is that, the config value will keep the new value during the script's execution and restore the old value at its termination while editing in config file will affect all scripts running.

> Note: `ini_set()` only affects the **current script** in which it is declared and not other scripts.

Answer (score 1):

No It does not overrate the php.ini file. It just makes changes makes php changes for the file and related files running the script.